# compiler error on calling derived class function using base class pointer which is not in base class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am learning C++ virtual functions.

```
#include<iostream>

class Base{
    virtual void fun(){
        std::cout<<"Base\n";
    }
};

class Derived:public Base{
    void fun(){
        std::cout<<"Derived\n";
    }
    virtual void fun1(){
        std::cout<<"Derived 1 \n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Base* b=new Derived();
    b->fun1();
}
```

I wrote this piece of code but it is not compiling. As per the concept of dynamic polymorphism, if we create a pointer of base class pointing to derived class, then we can call the functions of derived class, right?. Using virtual pointer of class Derived, we can call the fun1 function in virtual table, right?

But why it is not compiling here?

Comment: That's not how polymorphism works.  I see no `fun1()` function in the `Base` class.  Second, your `Base` class lacks a virtual destructor, thus if you were to attempt to issue a `delete b;`, you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: polymorphism is about substituting one type for another. I.e., being able to substitute `Derived` for `Base` for however `Base` is used. `Base` has no `fun1`, there's nothing to ever try to substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call any `Base` or `Derived` member functions from outside the classes since the functions are `private`. You need to make them `public`

The other problem:
`fun1` is not a member of `Base` so you can't call `fun1` via a base class pointer.

Two possible solutions:

- Declare a pure `virtual void fun1() = 0` in `Base`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rhGG3Kcvv)
- Cast `b` to a `Derived*` before calling: `static_cast<Derived*>(b)->fun1();`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sxPohv7nx)

Your program is also leaking memory. You need to `delete b;` and when you do it would now call the `Base` destructor only (with *undefined behavior* as a result) since your `Base` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor.

```
virtual ~Base() = default;
```

And then in `main`:

```
   // ...
   delete b;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gsxcjv315) using the smart pointer [`std::unique_ptr<Base>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of having to `delete` manually.